# Flash Drive refuses to be bootable

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, boot, usb-flash-drive

Hi I have used my Corsair Flash Voyager GT 16GB as a boot drive many times, bur recently it has refused to want to boot any OS, It just displays this blinking hyphen.

Comment: I never managed to properly boot off my Corsair Flash Voyager GT 16GB so +1 for interesting question!

Comment: It's something with your BIOS. Check to see what kind of usb bootable devices it can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use diskpart in order to make it bootable?

It should look something like this:

```
DISKPART> SELECT DISK 1
Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> CLEAN
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> SELECT PARTITION 1
Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> FORMAT FS=FAT32 QUICK
100 percent completed
DiskPart successfully formatted the volume.

DISKPART> ACTIVE
DiskPart marked the current partition as active.

DISKPART> EXIT
```

You can check guide at [this](http://blog.jmedved.com/2009/01/booting-windows-7-installation-from-usb.html) blog post for better looking formating.

Comment: Well actually I am trying to boot a Mac OS X Snow Leopard disk and I have restored the ISO to the flash drive but it refuses to boot even when I try to boot a Windows 7 installation

Comment: @GamerOfFreedom: Procedure should work regardless of operating system on it. USB drive itself is not a problem then.
If it was a PC, I would recommend restoring BIOS defaults.